# recursive division by 10 in python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to code a problem in python. It is to divide an integer number successively by 10 till the quotient < 10 i.e. no longer divisible by 10. here is my code - I am stuck, please help!

```
def recurDiv(N):
    '''
    N: a non-negative integer
    '''
    # Your code here
    Q=N/10
    R=N%10
    if Q<=10:
        return Q
    else:
        Q=recurDiv(N/10)*(N/10)**-1
        R=N%10
        return Q
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

You should work on clarifying your questions in the future but I think you're looking for this:

```
def recurDiv(N):
N/=10
R=N%10
if N<10:
    return N
else:
    return recurDiv(N)
```

But if you don't absolutely have to do it recursively you can get the same result with this:

```
def thing(N):
   print(str(N)[0])
```

though you might want put something in to raise an error if N is not an integer or float.

Comment: Thanks mini totent. I am doing an exercise to calculate the sum of the digits of a number N using the code you sent e.g. 126/10=12, 126%10=6. The sum of the digits is 1+2+6=9. This has to be done by recursion. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: I have a working bit of code that does just that but seeing as it seems you're trying to learn python you should try it yourself, but it does mean I can help. Also make sure you take the time to read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I tried this but it does not add remainder. I need the remainder total as sum of digits = remainder total:

Comment: def recurDiv(N):
   Total=0
   N/=10
   R=N%10
   Total=Total+R
   print Total
   if R<10:
     return R
   else:
     return Total

Comment: mini totent: I tried your code with N=2345 and added a print statement print R after "R=N%10"
I got R as 4 instead of 5; maybe a bug?

Comment: No it isn't a bug in my code, the code I gave you is only designed to output the first digit. The problem is it divides by 10 immediately, eliminating the last digit. Keep that in mind and try to work around it. Here's the full thing if you feel you really need it: http://goo.gl/80lfRp